# Creating sphinx table in mysql crashes mysql - why?

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

I've got the latest version of sphinx installed.  I have created the index with no problems and searchd starts up with no problems.

However, whenever I try to create a test table (straight from the docs I might add) mysql crashes.

I'm at wits end here.

Any ideas are appreciated.

G-Man

Here's the query:

> CREATE TABLE t1
>   (
>       id          INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>       weight      INTEGER NOT NULL,
>       query       VARCHAR(3072) NOT NULL,
>       group_id    INTEGER,
>       INDEX(query)
>   ) ENGINE=SPHINX CONNECTION="sphinx://localhost:9312/test";

Comment: For the benefit of those who might want to look into this but have never even heard of sphinx (the software) you could help out by listing the table creation query for us to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding this rather confusing and a bit of a look over the Shpinx web site doesn't make things much clearer but, as I understand it, Sphinx adds functionality to MySQL datbases, supporting MyISAM and InnoDB. The creation query tells MySQL to create a table using the sphinx engine, which is not something MySQL normally understands. I therefore suspect that the query is either incorrect or incomplete. Alternatively, some component of Shpinx that should allow MySQL to recognise the new sphinx engine isn't working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Has your MySQL binary been built using a correctly SphinxSE-patched source?

Anything in your MySQL error logs?

Have you been able to create *any* SphinxSE tables?